# abp.io IdentityUser required properties

Tags: abp

following the [documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/5.0/Object-Extensions) documentation I have no problem adding properties to IdentityUser, but if I want to add the RequiredAttribute to Name and Surname it is ignored, did I miss something or is it a limitation of the Blazor UI?

```
ObjectExtensionManager.Instance
            .AddOrUpdateProperty<string>(
                new[]
                {
                    typeof(IdentityUserDto),
                    typeof(IdentityUserCreateDto),
                    typeof(IdentityUserUpdateDto)
                },
                "Name",
                property =>
                {
                    property.Attributes.Add(new RequiredAttribute());
                }
            );
```

[image]